# How can I sync my system time with that of a database?

Tags: sync, database, time

I need my laptops timestamp to be the same as that of a database, is there a utility I can use for this?

So far, I'm having to run `select systimestamp from dual;` on my database, working out the difference in time against my clock, and adjusting it manually.

Its quite awkward, and goes out of sync often. I also need to be precise (within 5 seconds) and its a nuisance..

Comment: Might this be better suited to SO? If so can a mod please migrate? thanks

Comment: Is the DB server in the same LAN like your laptops? Do you have administrative access to the server where your database is running on?

Comment: On same network yes, but I don't have access to server where DB is located, just SQLPlus connection. Thinking if a batch script could do this for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have at least two options:

1. Ask the database admin to install a NTP (Network Time Protocol) server on the machine. You should then be able to retrieve the time from the DB servers with your laptops (instead of synching with a time server over the internet).
2. Ask the database admin if it is possible to synch the server with an internet-hosted time server. You then need to synch the notebooks' time with that same time server to get the laptops into synch with the database server.